# How to call SetDefaultDllDirectories before cgo loads library?

Tags: go, dll, cgo

I want to secure my go app against dll hijacking. Some DLLs I load are vulnerable and lookup system DLLs (like winmm.dll) in local path (./) first. To prevent this, I call this at first in my **main()** function:

```
windows.SetDefaultDllDirectories(LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32)
```

I can see this working, because some later DLL call is affected (I needed to provide full local path).

But for another library loaded by CGO, it does not seem to have any effect. Therefore I assume that CGO imports and loads the lib before my **main()** function is executed. I can see this in Process Explorer, where libs like winmm.dll are still searched in local path.

I load the lib in CGO like this:

```
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L . -lmylib
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mylib.h>
```

Is there a way to have my **SetDefaultDllDirectories()** call in **main()** affecting this lib, too?

Comment: How is that `mylib` linked in? Is it a DLL, and you can see a dependency on it in your executable via something like `depends.exe`?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible. The following line makes cgo compile for compiletime:

```
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L . -lmylib
```

By this, the kernel loads *mylib* during runtime even before any code in **func main()** is executed. Therefore, if a library is linked for compiletime like here, it is not possible to execute **SetDefaultDllDirectories()** before the library is loaded.

**Hints for people with the same problem to solve:**

- You can use a **manifest entry** to force loading named libraries from specific paths.
- You may need to ask the **vendor of the library** to provide you a version that uses LoadLibraryEx() API for loading the system libs specifically from system path ony.